# PHP - Design a stateless class

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I want to design a stateless class, for reusing the same instance in several places of the application without have any side effect. This is necessary because many dependency injection containers always return the same instance of the class.

Let's assume we have the `DirectoryUtils` class:

```
<?php

class DirectoryUtils{

  private $dir;

  public function __constructor($dir){
    if($this->checkDirectory($dir)){
      $this->dir = $dir;
    }else{
      throw new Exception("Invalid Directory");
    }
  }

  public function deleteAllFiles(){
    // code to delete all files in $this->dir;
  }

  public function renameDirectory($newName){
    // code to rename $this->dir name to $newName
  }

  private function checkDirectory($dir){
    // check if directory exists, is writable...
  }

}
```

A single instance of this class is uncomfortable to reuse. How to make it stateless?

Comment: StateLess == No idea of what has happened before.

Comment: *This is necessary because many dependency injection containers always return the same instance of the class* - many of them also allow you to work around this. Which ones have you tried?

Comment: @iainn PHP-DI will remove prototype scope in the next major version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to widen the scope you are investigating here: what is a meaningful service you can put in the DI container for reuse?

The problem with your class is not that it's stateful, but that its name reflects a misunderstanding of its purpose. This class represents *a specific directory* so should be named appropriately, e.g.

```
$my_home_dir = new Directory('/home/imsop');
$your_home_dir = new Directory('/home/abskmj');
$diff_tool->compareDirs($my_home_dir, $your_home_dir);
```

In your DI container, you would then put several specific instances of this class, for the specific directories you need to access, e.g.

```
[
    'CacheDir' => function($config) { 
        return new Directory($config['cache_path']); 
    },
    'LogDir' => function($config) { 
        return new Directory($config['log_path']); 
    }
]
```

Another type of service you might create is a *factory*, which abstracts part of the file system, and gives you different `Directory` objects, e.g.:

```
$my_home_dir = $factory->getHomeDir('imsop');
```

Here, the state constructed in the DI might be a base directory to work within:

```
[
     'DirectoryFactory' => function($config) { 
         return new DirectoryFactory($config['base_dir_path']); 
     }
]
```

Neither of these classes is "stateless", but both are *immutable* - once constructed, you do not change them to point at a different directory, you use a different instance for each purpose.

The `DirectoryFactory` class could in fact be stateless by having all the logic hard-coded (e.g. "a home directory is always `'/home/' . $user_name`"). This could still be useful to put in the DI container, because you could substitute a version with different hard-coded rules, or a test mock. However, as shown, the lack of state is not a necessary pre-condition for it being useful as a "singleton" in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make it stateless

You do not talk about 'stateless' here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless

Make your functions static: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

i.e.

```
class DirectoryUtils {
    ...

    public static function renameDirectory($newName) {
        ...
    }

}
```

then you simply call it like this:

```
DirectoryUtils::renameDirectory($name);
```

Comment: I'm not talking about static method... look here: http://php-di.org/doc/scopes.html

Comment: you are talking about singleton then.

Comment: Singleton scope (related to PHP-DI), not the singleton design pattern.

Comment: I strongly suggest you read [how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) then.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule for a stateless class is not having any instance variables/properties to store the state. The class methods are similar to utility or helper function working on the arguments only.

Rewriting your class:

```
<?php

class DirectoryUtils{      

  public function deleteAllFiles($dir){
    // code to delete all files in $dir;
  }

  public function renameDirectory($dir, $newName){
    // code to rename $dir name to $newName
  }
}
```

Comment: `The basic rule for a stateless class is not having any instance variables/properties to store the state` then why even have a constructor?

Comment: PHP doesn't add a default constructor. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909073/why-php-has-no-default-constructor). However, a constructor is not required if all the methods are static.

Comment: Actually, it may have some shared property, for example a database connection that can be shared across calls

Comment: @abskmj A constructor is not required ever. The issue discussed in your reference is that when you create a sub-class you have to *know* whether the parent has a constructor, to know whether to call it; but if there isn't one, you can just skip the call to it, and there is no problem. So providing an empty one is *helpful* if you expect people to be inheriting from the class, but it is not *required*.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP, I agree, the context of this discussion is different. I have updated by code.